# What is the correct location (MVC-wise) for iOS app event handlers?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am writing an iOS app that registers for call events (not-in-call, dialing, disconnected etc).
I have code that registers for the call event, but I'm not sure where is the correct location to put it (in the Model? In the Controller?).

All samples place the code in the app delegate, but that seems awkward. After all, the app delegate is not part of MVC.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd argue it is very much a controller!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After all, the app delegate is not part of MVC.

I could argue, but I have a feeling you worry too much about the "correct design". If you want to change the place of these event handlers, I'd put them somewhere in the controller (certainly not model, because they are not data providers...)

But after all, why are they "awkward" in the app delegate? That's **exactly** why the singleton application object has a delegate: system-wide events shall notify the app (and its delegate), respectively, and not some internal part of the application. That's mixing things up.

Answer (score 0):

Since these events control parts of your application the best answer would be: in a controller. 
This Apple style to put lots of stuff in the delegate is indeed bad coding practice.